# Can maven deduce and/or build an appropriate directory structure

Tags: java, maven

To better understand the Builder design pattern, I have downloaded a code demonstration which I am now trying to compile using maven. The demonstration code is made available in a single directory but the various `java` files have import statements reading

```
import aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.A;
import aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.B;
import aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.C;
import aaa.bbb.ccc.eee.D;
import aaa.bbb.ccc.eee.E;
import aaa.bbb.ccc.eee.F;
import aaa.bbb.ccc.fff.G;
import aaa.bbb.ccc.fff.H;
import aaa.bbb.ccc.fff.I;
import aaa.bbb.ccc.fff.J;
import aaa.bbb.ccc.ggg.K;
```

with Main.java expected to be in directory `ccc`.

I'm relatively new to `maven` having generally built packages directly in `eclipse` so I've got a couple of questions relating to `maven` which, whilst relevant to this particular demonstration, are also relevant to some other projects I have:

- Is it possible for `maven` to use the `import` statements in the various
  `java` files to infer and build an appropriate directory structure, including the target structure?
- Is it possible for `maven` to move the files, currently in a single
  directory, into their appropriate directories?
- If I were to put build the directory structure manually and move the java files to their correct positions, is it possible to have `maven` build the appropriate pom.xml file?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to link the repository you're looking at?

Comment: I've the feeling that Maven is not at all what you expect it to be. It's a dependency manager and a "builder"/"packager". It doesn't read files content nor move files (except with some plugins for some tasks). Also Maven does not build the `pom.xml`, you write it so that Maven can work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a wrong comprehension about maven. Maven will not organize your Java code for you.

Maven helps you to compile and test your Java code and create a jar File containing your Java code.

Therefore you have to create a pom.xml for your Eclipse Project with your configuration. Which could be supported by maven as described at https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html or Eclipse creating new Maven Project. Maven is assuming some default configuration like sourceDirectory in Eclipse Project is `src/main/java` and more.

And the answers are: No. No. No.

You could create maven plugins which are doing your desired Things but maven itself will not do those  things.

Comment: Thank you. Your last comment is especially interesting. I take it that no such plug-in already exists, but now that I know of the possibility, I shall also search.